# Render custom page/s after validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the High Voltage gem (https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/) for a site with masses of static pages. The site has three unique forms all which are handled by the 'forms' controller/model.

Now all is working well when fields which requires validation are populated, but when validation fails it jumps from the 'pages' controller (High Voltage) back to the 'forms' controller and renders /form/new, instead of, for instance, /pages/quotes - which is understandable as it's default behaviour.

I'm also checking for validation in the form:

```
= form_for @form, :validate => true do |f|
  - if @form.errors[:name].present?
    .control-group.error
      = f.label "Your Name"
      = f.text_field :name
  - else
    = f.label "Your Name"
    = f.text_field :name
```

Any idea how I can re-render the current page (which renders the specific form) after validation fails instead of directing to /forms/new

Any advice appreciated, thanks!